# (Date Difference Finder) Pass result of a select query into another select query inside if-else loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, date-difference

I am trying to finding date difference between today's date and given date in the table.Some rows has 1 date while others has 2 dates (take earlier date). I tried with dynamic variable and temp table  but still not working

[image: Here is the input table]

```
else
begin
SELECT * INTO #result2
 FROM 
 ( 

  declare @t date
  set @t = '
  select SUBSTRING(Availability, PATINDEX('% [0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', [Availability]), 11) as [Date Part] from [ScrappedData_Regina] '

-- extracts date part from a column

  select  distinct [Product Name],[SKU],DATEDIFF(day,cast(@t as date),cast(GETDATE() as date)) as [Delivery Date]  from ScrappedData_Regina
)  -- i want to pass the date part in this select statement
```

The first query will give result as
[image: firstquery result]

And I want the same result for second query too for two dates case.

[image: secondquery result]

Finally combine both the result in a table

Comment: Sample data and expected result will help us to understand better

Comment: sample data has been given

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do that in one query (if I understand what you're trying to do).  Remove the first query and replace the second one with this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Product Name],
                [SKU],
                DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(
                    SUBSTRING(Availability,
                        PATINDEX('% [0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', [Availability]), 11) AS DATE),
                        CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
                    ) AS [Delivery Date]
FROM ScrappedData_Regina
```

Comment: thanks but i forgot to show you the input table . In the table some rows has one date while other also has two dates and I want the earlier date.So both the queries are required. I want a combined result